# How to suppress application logging messages from a node.js application when running unit tests?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

While unit-testing my node.js application (which is basically a REST backend) using mocha and supertest, I need only the test-specific message on the screen, but the stdout is also cluttered with application log messages.

I start the unit test with:

```
mocha -R spec .
```

... and get this output (this is what it *should not* be):

```
[App] Listening on port 3000 ...
[App] Starting app, hooray!

  Project API
    GET /projects
[App] entering "projects" module ...
      √ should return an array of projects (317ms)
```

I marked the application log message with [App]. What I *really want* would be this output from the unit test:

```
  Project API
    GET /projects
      √ should return an array of projects (317ms)
```

How can I suppress console.log/warn/error output by the application interspersed with Mocha's reporter output?

**SOLUTION:**

Following dankohn's approach, I ended up like this, which solves my issue (using [winston](http://github.com/flatiron/winston) for logging):

(in node's "main" server file, server.js:)

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
    logger = new (winston.Logger)({
        transports: [
            new (winston.transports.Console)(),
            new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: 'foo.log' })
        ]
    });
} else {
    // while testing, log only to file, leaving stdout free for unit test status messages
    logger = new (winston.Logger)({
        transports: [
            new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: 'foo.log' })
        ]
    });
}
```

... and to set the env variable, each unit test file starts with:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
```

Comment: Hi, I have the some problem and I have used a similar approach to fix it but I still get mongoose errors in the console. Do you know how to handle that?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In your app.js:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
  app.use(express.logger());
}
```

At the top of each of your mocha files:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
```

**Update:**

We use this function in our import code:

```
function logExceptOnTest(string) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
    console.log(string);
  }
}
```

Then, replace all your `console.log('it worked')` with `logExceptOnTest('it worked')`. The basic trick is to use environment variables as a global flag as to the level of logging you want.

Comment: Gee - you've guessed correctly that I use Express. Thanks for the quick response. I cannot use your solution as is, because express.logger() AFAIU only logs the requests/responses but cannot be used for application logging (debug messages etc.). But extracting the essence from your idea, the way to go seems: (1) get rid of console.log (which I am currently using) (2) use a configurable logging framework instead (3) configure logging facility based on the NODE_ENV env setting. Now I have to get my hands dirty on (2) and (3) ...

Comment: See my update. If you want much more logging functionality, see https://github.com/flatiron/winston but we haven't needed it yet.

Comment: I do want logging messages while unit testing, because when writing the unit tests (in advance), I would still like to see what's going on under the hood of the app. So, I will employ a adapted version of your suggestions: use winston for configuring logging facilities and use the env variable (like you suggested) to differentiate between "testing" and "not testing" mode. When in "testing" mode, log application messages to a specified file (keeping the unit test output clean) - and in "not testing" mode (= production mode), log application messages to stdout, to be piped to e.g. forever.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I ended up using rlogger and just wrapping the log level around a check for the 'testing' string in the environment variable. i.e. only log errors during testing, otherwise log all during normal operation.

Answer (score 17):

Here's a pretty simple solution that uses [SinonJS](https://sinonjs.org/)'s [test stubs](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.3.0/stubs/) to suppress all `console.log/info/warn/error` statements before running your tests.

```
// my-method.js

export function myMethod() {
    console.log(`I'm about to return true`)
    return true
}
```

---

```
// my-method.test.js

import {describe, it, before} from 'mocha'
import chai from 'chai'
import sinon from 'sinon'
import chalk from 'chalk'
import {myMethod} from './my-method.js'

const expect = chai.expect

describe(chalk.underline('My Test Group'), () => {

    before(() => {
        sinon.stub(console, 'log')  // disable console.log
        sinon.stub(console, 'info')  // disable console.info
        sinon.stub(console, 'warn')  // disable console.warn
        sinon.stub(console, 'error')  // disable console.error
    })

    describe('myMethod', () => {
        it('should return true', () => {
            expect(myMethod()).to.be.true  // without printing to the console
        })
    })
})
```

---

```
// output

My Test Group
  myMethod
    ✓ should return true
```

Comment: This looks like the approach I want but I can't make it work. I'm already using sinon, those `stub` calls should be all that's needed, right?

Comment: Sometimes I need to put the stub/restore inside the test itself to get this to work

Comment: This is the correct approach.. and should be accepted as a solution!

Answer (score 8):

Already answered but thought I would add that you can do this user winston.add()

```js
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.File)({filename: 'node.log'})
    ]
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
    logger.add(winston.transports.Console, {prettyPrint: true});
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `mocha-suppress-logs` to hide logs generated by successuful tests but still keep the ones generated by failed tests to ease debugging.

Install:

```sh
npm install --save-dev mocha-suppress-logs
```

Then use it like this:

```js
const suppressLogs = require('mocha-suppress-logs');
 
describe('Something', () => {
  suppressLogs();
 
  it('should do something', () => {
    // test code
  });
});
```

You can also do so globally for the entire test suite.

Here's a link to the module:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-suppress-logs

Answer (score 0):

Take a close look at `the-log`. To hide logs you just need to activate silence mode once in some of your test script:

```js
require('the-log').silent(); // That's all!!))
      
describe('Something', () => {
  it('should do something', () => {
    // test code
  });
});
```

More about `the-log`: https://github.com/ivanoff/the-log

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party, but straight **into the test file**, you can safely write:

```js
console.log = () => {};
```

and voilà, your application won't show any logs, while mocha will.