# Can I silence out mocha when test fails?

Tags: mocha.js

When using mocha to test every changes that I made, sometimes I need to do `console.log` on source code. But, the long stack trace that reporter force me to scroll up the output (stack trace can be hundreds of lines).

Can I make it to just reports like this:

- success
- success
- fails
- fails
- fails
- fails
- fails
- fails

so i can just see to the output without scrolling up?

Comment: `--bail` might be of use here? Mocha will then exit on the first test failure.

Comment: but that means it doesn't produce the output of the rest unit test. Any better way?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of sorry. The only other suggestion I would make is don't use `console.log` for debugging. Use [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector). It works the same as the chrome development tools and you can debug via break points and watches. No need for looking through the mocha output.

Comment: It's possible, but you pretty much need to use a more advanced logger. See the answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709882/how-to-suppress-application-logging-messages-from-a-node-js-application-when-run).