# Suppress log outputs in chai

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I'm currently using chai and chai-http to test some HTTP responses for a node app. The problem I have is that it logs the server response status and timings to the console every time I use `chai.request(...)`. In turn this makes it's way into a mocha test output file with xunit and causes my CI solution to break.

An example of the test is:

```
        chai.request(server)
            .get('/')
            .end(function(err, res){
                expect(res).to.have.status(200);
                expect(res.text).to.have.string("Maintenance");
                done();
            });
```

Logs:

```
GET / 200 17.807 ms - 305
```

What would you suggest to suppress chai's logging?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't so much an issue of suppressing logging in [chai](/questions/tagged/chai) as it is suppressing logging in [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js).

This solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22710649/438581) will give you some ideas.

And the [debug](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug) or [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) utilities would be another option.

Comment: This looks like a [link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) that could use some elaboration so it stands on its own, or should otherwise be a comment.