# How to disable debug console output generated by winston elasticstack client and transport?

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, winston

I'm using `winston v3.2.1`, `winston-elasticsearch v0.8.8` and `@elastic/elasticsearch v7.6.1` to push log entries for my NodeJS services to an Elastic Search cluster v7.6.2.

My logger is constructed as follows (see https://github.com/vanthome/winston-elasticsearch and https://www.npmjs.com/package/@elastic/elasticsearch):

```js
import { Client } from '@elastic/elasticsearch';
import winston, { Logger } from 'winston';
import { ElasticsearchTransport } from 'winston-elasticsearch';
import { ELASTIC_HOST, ELASTIC_PORT, LOG_LEVEL } from './environment';
...
        this.logger = winston.createLogger({
            transports: [
                new ElasticsearchTransport({
                    client: new Client({
                        node: `http://${ELASTIC_HOST}:${ELASTIC_PORT}`
                    }),
                    index: 'sector',
                    level: LOG_LEVEL // Events I log that are 'info' or worse will be transported.
                })
            ]
        });
```

I then log using the `logger` reference directly:

```js
this.logger.info(`Kill signal received: ${signal}`);
```

I can see that my log entries are being pushed to the Elastic Search cluster but the console logs are flooded with debug output from the `elasticsearch` and `winston:elasticsearch` loggers. I think they belong to the Elastic Node client and Elasticsearch Transport implementations.

```
2020-05-12T22:10:10.114Z elasticsearch Nothing to resurrect
...
2020-05-12T22:10:10.116Z winston:elasticsearch starting bulk writer
...
2020-05-12T22:10:18.122Z winston:elasticsearch nothing to flush
2020-05-12T22:10:20.123Z winston:elasticsearch tick
2020-05-12T22:10:20.123Z winston:elasticsearch nothing to flush
```

My services run inside Docker containers and I don't want the Docker logs to flood with debug noise. I tried to set the transport levels to `error` and even removing the `Console` transport completely but the debug noise persists. I tried the following to suppress the console output without much luck:

- `winston.level = 'error';`
- `winston.transports.Console.level = 'error';`
- `winston.transports.Console.silent = true;`
- `this.logger.remove(winston.transports.Console);`
- `winston.remove(winston.transports.Console);`

I found a couple of threads on the subject but no luck:

- https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/175
- [Disable winston logging when running unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363292/disable-winston-logging-when-running-unit-tests)

It's almost like the client and transporter is using a separate logging mechanism.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I've confirmed that the output was not generated by winston at all. That's why I couldn't disable it using the approaches I listed above.

It looks like the `ElasticsearchTransport` implementation uses a package called [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug). It turns on when a pattern is specified in the `DEBUG` environment variable. I had it set to `DEBUG=*` so that I could see Express output. The debug noise stopped when I removed the environment variable.

**If you see debug noise in your console, check that the [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) package is not the cause. Many packages appear to use it.**